# Implementing material deformation

Tags: mathematics, physics

I want to implement deformation of plastic material, like plasticine for example. Where should I start to study? What technique should I use?

Thank you for any advice.

**EDIT**

I want to use it in real-time in kind of a 3D game, not a physics simulation. When I "push" on the plasticine, it is expected to spill. I want to rotate it or any other actions.

Look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDbVHEg5qC4

Comment: 3D? 2D? Baked deformation? Dynamic deformation? Shearing? Melting? Brittleness? Elasticity? Material weakening from stress? You need to add more details on what you exactly what.

Answer (score 3):

Is this for use in a real-time game or as a high-accuracy simulation? If you're just looking at it as an effect for a game, then it's quite possible that you could get away with using a procedural texture, determined by CPU, combined with a vertex-shader to move your vertices about as desired at run-time.

If you're interested in accuracy, then you would need to take into account various material properties, such as Young's Modulus, limit of elasticity, Hardness, etc. (I'm not a material scientist so I don't know all of the variables affecting plastic/elastic deformation). I guess you'd first determine how accurate you want your simulation to be, and then just use this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_%28mechanics%29) to find out what variables you need, and then search for each of those variables for each material you want ([this site](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is useful). You would then presumably have a very-high polygon object, or tessellate it as necessary.

I also imagine you would have to have per-vertex collision detection, to ensure you don't end up with impossible shapes (self-intersection tests etc.), also, you could use the tessellation feature in DirectX 11, as mentioned earlier, to help smoothen your shape as you deform it (a cube only needs 6 faces, but when morphed you'll need to add more faces).

Hope this helps, I'd like to see how your project progresses! :)

Comment: Those links are very good ones, especially the second one.  Also, overall this is a high-quality answer (+1) because it's informative, helpful, and also digresses slightly into an area that the questioner will likely get into (that's particularly helpful from a preparatory standpoint).